Problem with python code that can execute a console command from another computer
I am new to python and could need some help here. I am trying to code a programm that can execute commands from one device to another. So I have client and server. My current problem is that after sending a command it reconnects with REQUEST_COMMAND at the end of its name(See image) and I dont get the output.enter image description here
client.py:
import socket
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='client.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

connected_servers = {}
server_connections = {}
servers_file = "servers.json"

def load_servers():
    if os.path.exists(servers_file):
        with open(servers_file, 'r') as file:
            return json.load(file)
    return {}

def save_servers():
    with open(servers_file, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(connected_servers, file, indent=4)

def handle_server(conn, addr):
    try:
        hostname = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        logging.info(f"Connected to server: {hostname} at {addr}")
        print(f"Connected to server: {hostname} at {addr}")
        connected_servers[hostname] = {"status": "online", "last_seen": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        server_connections[hostname] = conn
        save_servers()
        update_server_list()
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if data == 'REQUEST_COMMAND':
                logging.debug(f"Received REQUEST_COMMAND from {hostname}")
                print(f"Received REQUEST_COMMAND from {hostname}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Connection error with {hostname}: {e}")
        print(f"Connection error with {hostname}: {e}")
        connected_servers[hostname]["status"] = "offline"
        connected_servers[hostname]["last_seen"] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        server_connections.pop(hostname, None)
        save_servers()
        update_server_list()

def start_server():
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 5000

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen()
        logging.info(f"Server started on {host}:{port}")
        print(f"Server started on {host}:{port}")
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            logging.info(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
            print(f"Accepted connection from {addr}")
            threading.Thread(target=handle_server, args=(conn, addr)).start()

def send_command(server, command):
    try:
        conn = server_connections[server]
        logging.info(f"Sending command to {server}: {command}")
        print(f"Sending command to {server}: {command}")
        conn.sendall(command.encode())
        
        # chunks to handle larger outputs
        output = b""
        while True:
            chunk = conn.recv(4096)
            if not chunk:
                break
            output += chunk
        
        logging.info(f"Received output from {server}: {output.decode()}")
        print(f"Received output from {server}: {output.decode()}")
        return output.decode()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Connection error with {server}: {e}")
        print(f"Connection error with {server}: {e}")
        return f"Connection error with {server}: {e}"

def open_terminal(server):
    terminal_window = tk.Toplevel()
    terminal_window.title(f"Terminal - {server}")

    terminal_output = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(terminal_window, state='disabled', wrap='word')
    terminal_output.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    command_entry = tk.Entry(terminal_window)
    command_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.X)

    def execute_command(event=None):
        command = command_entry.get()
        if command:
            logging.info(f"Entered command: {command}")
            print(f"Entered command: {command}")
            terminal_output.config(state='normal')
            terminal_output.insert(tk.END, f"> {command}\n")
            terminal_output.config(state='disabled')
            command_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            try:
                output = send_command(server, command)
                terminal_output.config(state='normal')
                terminal_output.insert(tk.END, f"{output}\n")
                terminal_output.config(state='disabled')
            except Exception as e:
                terminal_output.config(state='normal')
                terminal_output.insert(tk.END, f"Error: {e}\n")
                terminal_output.config(state='disabled')

    command_entry.bind("<Return>", execute_command)

def update_server_list():
    for widget in server_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for server, info in connected_servers.items():
        status = info["status"]
        last_seen = info["last_seen"]
        display_text = f"{server} - {status}"
        if status == "offline":
            display_text += f" (Last seen: {last_seen})"
        server_button = tk.Button(server_frame, text=display_text, command=lambda s=server: open_terminal(s))
        server_button.pack(pady=5)

def create_ui():
    global server_frame
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Client UI")

    server_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    server_frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    threading.Thread(target=start_server, daemon=True).start()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connected_servers = load_servers()
    create_ui()


server.py
import socket
import time
import subprocess
import platform
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='server.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def execute_command(command):
    try:
        logging.info(f"Executing command: {command}")
        print(f"Executing command: {command}")
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout + result.stderr
        logging.info(f"Command output: {output}")
        print(f"Command output: {output}")
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error executing command: {e}")
        print(f"Error executing command: {e}")
        return str(e)

def server_program():
    host = '127.0.0.1'  
    port = 5000  

    while True:
        try:
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect((host, port))
                hostname = platform.node()
                s.sendall(hostname.encode())
                logging.info(f"Connected to client at {host}:{port} as {hostname}")
                print(f"Connected to client at {host}:{port} as {hostname}")
                while True:
                    s.sendall(b'REQUEST_COMMAND')
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    if data:
                        command = data.decode()
                        logging.info(f"Received command from client: {command}")
                        print(f"Received command from client: {command}")
                        output = execute_command(command)
                        logging.info(f"Sending output to client: {output}")
                        print(f"Sending output to client: {output}")
                        s.sendall(output.encode())
                        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                        break  
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Connection error: {e}")
            print(f"Connection error: {e}")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_program()



You'll need a better framing scheme than just blindly reading 1024 bytes off the socket and hoping that's all. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65109552/51685 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/77416024/51685
